# Javascript - determine if an Excel cell is empty or not

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm using javascript to proccess an excel file. I need to be able to determin if a cell is empty or not. I've tried 4 things and all of them didn't work good.

```
if(cell == null);
if(cell == undefined);
if(cell == "");
if(!cell);
```

the first three didn't work at all. The last method returned false when I check a cell containing a date (and I need to go through dates).

Can anyone please tell me what an empty cell returns please?

Comment: First check the `typeof cell` with empty and non empty value. We don't know whats the definition of cell is.

Comment: What API are you using to access the data? As @Rahil says, we need to understand what `cell` is before we can help you.

Comment: Side note: There is no functional difference between `x == null` and `x == undefined`. Both will be true if `x` is `null`, and both will be true if `x` is `undefined`, and both will be false if `x` is anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rahil Wazir. I've tried to use typeof on the cells values. the filled cells returned "date" and the empty cells returned "undefined". So this is the way to determine if